# Unseeming boot loop on laptop running Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, boot, performance, operating-systems

I have an Acer Aspire E1-410 which is running Windows 8. Currently when I turn it on, it takes around 5-10 minutes to boot up and during the boot sequence, it seems that it is stuck on a black screen boot loop since the fan turns off and on again. The laptop does eventually boot up.

I don't really have any spare parts for the laptop so I can't test out if it's a hardware issue. I have also checked the event viewer which had a warning and an error for the Intel Management Engine Interface which have already uninstalled and the issue is still not fixed.

Comment: How long does it take for you to boot to a linux liveCD based off a USB stick?

Comment: i still have not tried that. i go ahead and see. thanks